# How to create a form with the same object as a previous form

Tags: c#

I want to be able to create a new form which can use the same objects/instances_of_a_class as the form before it. How do you create a new form that can use the same objects when you click a button

My current code for a new form is :

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 F2 = new Form2();
    F2.ShowDialog();
}
```

The new form (F2) should be able to access my List of objects which have been instantiated in the first form. I need access to the list of objects from both forms.

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to the second form that allows to pass the object

```cs
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private MyClass _myObject;

    public Form2(MyClass myObject)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myObject = myObject;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Then in the first form

```cs
private MyClass _theObject = new MyClass()

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 F2 = new Form2(_theObject);
    F2.ShowDialog();
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _theObject.DoSomething();
}
```

Note that a form is just a class like any other. Also, the forms designer does **not** need a default (parameter less) constructor as is often mistakenly assumed.

Other possibilities are to create public properties or methods used to pass parameters.

```cs
// in Form2

public MyClass Data { get; set; }

// or

public void Initialize(MyClass data)
{
    _theObject = data;
}
```

Then in form1

```cs
Form2 F2 = new Form2();

F2.Data = _theObject;
//or
F2.Initialize(_theObject);

F2.ShowDialog();
```

Yet another possibility is to pass `Form1` to `Form2` using one of the ways shown above and to add public properties or methods to `Form1` exposing the required data or functionality, so that `Form2` can access them through the `Form1` object.